# owncloud refusing to access data directory

Tags: php, permissions, owncloud

I am trying to fix an OwnCloud sever. I am stuck since a day, and I am starting to despair. Owncloud (set up on arch linux) says:

```
Data directory ( /data/ocdata) is invalid

Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.
Cannot create "data" directory ( /data/ocdata)

This can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the root directory.
```

So I did the following (out of desperation):

```
sudo chown -R 777 /data/ocdata
```

an ls on ocdata gives:

```
ls /data/ocdata -a -l

total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 http http 4096 Sep 14 20:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 14 20:18 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 http http    2 Sep 14 20:40 .ocdata
```

The config.php says:

```
 <?php
 $CONFIG = array (
 'instanceid' => 'ocac7c1e1b0a',
 'passwordsalt' => 'f30d85305490ef50994a3231be3017',
 'trusted_domains' =>
 array (
     0 => '10.10.10.5',
     ),
     'datadirectory' => ' /data/ocdata',
     'dbtype' => 'pgsql',
     'version' => '7.0.2.1',
     'dbname' => 'owncloud',
     'dbhost' => 'localhost',
     'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
     'dbuser' => '---',
     'dbpassword' => '---',
     'installed' => true,
     );`
```

what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Please note the leading space in ' /data/ocdata'. Remove it and you will be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (on my IIS 6.0)

```
'datadirectory' =>  'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\owncloud\data'
```

Answer (score -2):

My Server is Centos 7 with Plesk 12.0.18. These days I had the same problem with OwnCloud.

For OwnCloud using the root-Plesk-user, I added a new Webspace to my Root-Server. It has its homedirectory in /var/www/vhosts/%domain%/httpdocs, which is located on a smaller SSD Drive.
Because I have this huge backup-disk within this server, I tried to set the ./data/-folder to this other drive. The new folder was supposed to be /data/cloud/

Therefore I had to do the same things you did here. But It didnt work. I tried everything like apache aliases, symbolic directorys, copying hidden files too, playing around with chmod, chown ...
The directory was there and had the right owner and the right permissions.

> Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root

The solution is quite simple: The problem seemed to be the **open_basedir**
Screen within Plesk: https://downfight.de/grafiken/dimi/5a619a19950af98b6b68c237554d71ad.png
(original value: {WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/} ) 
Change it to:

> {WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/dev:/data/cloud

(adding /dev too fixes the /dev/urandom-Error for OwnCloud)

Afterwards I had to comit the changes within Plesk and then I edited the config.php again, to change the data-directory and it worked.

Comment: Well you can downrate this answer, but in my case this had been the single only fix that I succeded with. Can anyone explain why this is not a good answer?